# Weird overflow issue in Twitter Bootstrap and Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a Twitter Bootstrap well, which contains a [Select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) component.

Demo can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/U4KTM/1/

There are two problems in Chrome (not evident in FF or IE):

- There is an overflow issue in chrome causing vertical scrollbars in the well. This seems to be solved by the following css:

  .tab-content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
- The second problem in Chrome is that selecting an item in the bottom dropdown causes a weird jumping issue in the well, and then some of the well content dissapears off the top.

The code in question is as follows:

```
<div class="well">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab">First tab</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab">Second tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel1">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="bar" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="bar" class="selector">
                        <option value="0">First Option</option>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Second Option</option>
                        <option value="2">Third Option</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>                      
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="bar" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="bar" class="selector">
                        <option value="0">First Option</option>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Second Option</option>
                        <option value="2">Third Option</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to overwrite this CSS class `.tab-content`:

with:

```
.tab-content {
      overflow:visible;
 }
```

The style is located in :

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css

*line: 608*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well.  Seems you need to make a slight change to the select2.js and comment out the height in the _makeMaskCss.  This seem to happen with Bootstrap Responsive for me. The demo seems to work just fine.

```
function _makeMaskCss() {
            return {
                width  : Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollWidth,  $(window).width())//,
                //height : Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, $(window).height())
            }
        }
```